I've definitely done something wrong in my system of linear first-order DEs problem
So here is my problem.
$$y'_1 = y_1 - 4y_2$$ $$y'_2 = -2y_1 + 8y_2$$
Looks simple enough. So I set up a coefficient matrix to prepare to solve
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -4\\
    -2 & 8\\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     y'_1\\
    y'_2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\
$$
My first attempt was using cramer's rule, and obviously that didn't bring me anywhere closer to finding a solution so I am not even going to show my attempt at that... Next I went to find the eigenvalues,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda -1 & -4\\
    -2 & \lambda -8\\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix} = \lambda
    \begin{bmatrix}
     y_1\\
    y_2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\ ,
(\lambda-1)(\lambda-8)-8=\lambda^2-9\lambda
$$
So I find the characteristic equation and solve for $\lambda = 9,0$ with eigenvectors $x_1=(-1,2)$ ,  $ x_2=(4,1)$ respectively. Well now I know I can diagonalize, however after doing so I get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 9\\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     y'_1\\
    y'_2\\
    \end{bmatrix}$$ $$ y'_1=0$$
$$ y'_2=9y_2$$
So I am pretty sure $y_1 = C$ and $y_2 = \frac{9y^2}{2} +C$ are the general solutions, however when I look in the back of my textbook, none of the answer forms look like this.
Edit: Note I have not taken an ODE class, and through Calculus II I have only had a brief introduction to seperable DEs, so if you could explain my error in detail that would be appreciated.

You did everything correct until the final part where you should have written
$$Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
    y_1(t) \\
    y_2(t) \\
    \end{bmatrix} = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2$$
Update
$$Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
    y_1(t) \\
    y_2(t) \\
    \end{bmatrix} = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2 = c_1 e^{9t}\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    2 \\
    \end{bmatrix} + c_2 e^{0t} \begin{bmatrix}
    4 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
Can you continue?

So it looks like you set up $Y(t)$ as a linear combination of vectors, however what vectors are plugged in for $v_1$ and $v_2$? It looks like the answer should be $c_1e^{0t}v_1 = c_1v_1, c_1v_1 + c_2e^{9t}v_2$? Or are there infinite answers $v$?

The eigenvectors you found.  I will update to show more detail.

So $$\begin{pmatrix}
-C_1e^{9t} + 4\
2C_1e^{9t} + 1\
\end{pmatrix} = Y(t)$$

Almost -   I forgot $c_2$, now updated. Great work!

Ok so for $y_1 = -C_1e^{9t} + 4C_2$ we can still just say $y_1 = -C_1e^{9t} + C_2$ right?

Correct, since you have no ICs, the constants can be absorbed into another constant. Same goes for $y_2(t)$.

Another possible approach. Multiply the first equation by two and add to the second:
\begin{align*}
2y'_{1} + y'_{2} = (2y_{1} - 8y_{2}) + (-2y_{1} + 8y_{2}) = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow y_{2} = -2y_{1} + C
\end{align*}
Consequently, one has
\begin{align*}
y'_{1} = y_{1} - 4y_{2} = 9y_{1} - 4C& \Longleftrightarrow y'_{1} - 9y_{1} = -4C\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-9t}y_{1})' = -4Ce^{-9t}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{-9t}y_{1} = \frac{4C}{9}e^{-9t} + D\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y_{1} = \frac{4C}{9} + De^{9t}
\end{align*}
and, finally, one gets that
\begin{align*}
y_{2} = -2y_{1} + C = -\frac{8C}{9} - 2De^{9t} + C = \frac{C}{9} - 2De^{9t} 
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!
